# Getting error "Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" in iOS 7

Tags: ios, afnetworking, multipartform-data

I am using **AFNetworking** version "2.5.4" and creating **multipartform-data**  request. 
In my case code is working fine on iOS8 but issue on iOS 7. Getting Error

> "Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011
>   "Request failed: bad request (400)"
>
> UserInfo=0x19039c00
>   {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://xxx/api/abc/PostApi } { status code: 400,
>   headers {
>       Connection = close;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>       Date = "Wed, 20 May 2015 05:42:47 GMT";
>       Server = Apache; } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxx/api/abc/PostApi },
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400),
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227375 63636573
>   73223a66 616c7365 2c226d65 73736167 65223a22 4e6f2064 61746122
>   2c226461 7461223a 5b5d2c22 72657370 6f6e7365 5f636f64 65223a22
>   52433030 3033227d>}

This is my Code that have issue

`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLSessionUploadTask *postUploadTask;

__block int i=1;
            AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:postParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if (imageArray.count > 0) {
            long dataLenght = 0.0;
            for(UIImage *eachImage in imageArray)
            {
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(eachImage, .5);
                dataLenght = dataLenght + imageData.length;
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                i++;
            }

        }
    } error:nil];

    NSProgress *progress = nil;
    self.postUploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        [progress removeObserver:object forKeyPath:kProgressFractionCompleted context:kPostUpdateTypePostUpdate];
        completionBlock(responseObject, error, task);
    }];
    [self.postUploadTask resume];`
```

While this is working code on same api-:

```
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:urlString parameters:postParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if (imageArray.count > 0) {
            long dataLenght = 0.0;
            for(UIImage *eachImage in imageArray)
            {
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(eachImage, .5);
                dataLenght = dataLenght + imageData.length;
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                i++;
            }
        }
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

        completionBlock(responseObject, nil, task);

        [progress removeObserver:object forKeyPath:kProgressFractionCompleted context:kPostUpdateTypePostUpdate];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(operation, error, task);

    }];
    [op start];
```

But My requirement is to implement uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest. 
This is similar to issue"[Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235270/error-domain-com-alamofire-error-serialization-response-code-1011-request-fail)".

Please help me guys if have any idea about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a proxy like Charles to monitor what is being sent in iOS7 vs iOS8 and see what the difference is.

Comment: @Lefteris,  thanx for your suggestion. I checked my request header,  both are same.

Comment: Not just the header, check also the post body. Something is for sure different and causing a bad request!

Comment: I found the answer in this link. Really helpfull for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948561/response-failure-when-using-afhttprequestoperationmanager

Comment: Thank you everyone, In my case there was some server configuration issue. My request and response is working on another server.

Comment: this is your error messge: {"success":false,"message":"No data","data":[],"response_code":"RC0003"} Either server error or you failed to send the upload data

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding request serializer to your AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.

```
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *jsonRequestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [self.requestOperationManager setRequestSerializer:jsonRequestSerializer];
```